# A plugin where users can comment with Facebook or Twitter or OpenID

Tags: comments, facebook, twitter, openid

Is there any plugin where users can comment with Facebook or Twitter or OpenID...

Comment: Be aware that by offering such options (or even by *requiring* them, e.g. by using disqus) you allow companies to track your commentors (and maybe even visitors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [disqus](http://disqus.com/) on my site and it works quite well.

Comment: Seems pretty good.

Comment: I use Disqus too and have done for quite a while now, would definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Simple Twitter Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/) and [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/).