# Plugin to require Twitter or Facebook login before posting a comment

Tags: plugin-recommendation, comments, users, authentication

There are similar questions to this one (e.g. [A plugin where users can comment with Facebook or Twitter or OpenID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/a-plugin-where-users-can-comment-with-facebook-or-twitter-or-openid) or [Twitter/Facebook login for comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27890/twitter-facebook-login-for-comments)) but none of it fully addresses my scenario so let me ask a specific question.

I want to have "social commenting" on my blog and these are the requirements (ideally all should be fulfilled):

1. It should be **built-in comments, not a 3rd party service** like Disqus or IntenseDebate (I don't want to go into details, have my reasons)
2. **Comment form should be visible straight away**, i.e. no "you must be logged in to post comments" and then going through the main login screen etc.
3. However, I actually want **commenters to be authenticated** when they post comments, using either Twitter, Facebook or Wordpress (site's) login. Something like small icons below the text area as on Wordpress.com would be perfect.
4. Submitting a comment should **create a Wordpress user** so that from administration, I can see what they commented on, how many comments they have etc.

Couple of notes from my research so far:

- There are many plugins for social login, for instance [OA Social Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oa-social-login/). I have not tried them all but for instance this plugin cannot do 2+3 as far as I know.
- Theoretically the social login for comments should be part of the Jetpack plugin but I don't see it there.

Is my goal achievable in WP 3.3.1 and some mix of plugins?

Comment: Very good question! I am struggling to find a solution to the same requirement. It's not an unusual thing to want, yet WordPress comments fails to provide this functionality. You either have to open your comments to all comers, or do without social login.

Answer (score 2):

There is a premium plugin from [wpmudev.org](http://premium.wpmudev.org/) called [**Comments Plus**](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/comments-plus) for, I think, $17 that does include support. I'm not sure if it will add the user to WordPress but with support included they might help suss out a solution for you.

Comment: Any example of a blog using Comments Plus and requiring social login to post? I'm not sure from the screenshots whether this plugin is what I want or not but thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Have a look at their [blog](http://wpmu.org/) (which it was developed for).

I had a look around for something like this a few months back and their isn't much out there. Tempted to write my own and release it under GPL.

Comment: Let me know if you do :)